# Remove enclosing bracketing marks

Tags: awk

I have an awk function meant to remove the enclosing square brackets.  Now I want to adapt it to handle any bracketing mark.  What can I do ?

```
function debrac(mark,     str)
 {
  ## Remove enclosing bracket marks from string STR.

  renval = str ; gsub(/^\[|\]$/, "", str)
  return str
 }
```

Comment: post a testable string sample

Comment: make a character class of bracketing characters (L & R) ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simply expand your regular expression in gsub's argument for more brackets:

```
gsub(/^[\[\{\(]|[\]\}\)]$/, "", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `+` and, if that's what's required, remove the line beginning or ending requirement

```
% awk 'BEGIN{str = "A[[any]]word"; gsub(/\[+|\]+/, "", str); print str}'
Aanyword
```